# Jupyter/IPython custom autocomplete for cell magic

Tags: autocomplete, jupyter, ipython

I have read several discussions about this, but I am a bit stuck with some more advanced behavior I am seeking. As a preamble, I am using

```
def load_ipython_extension(ipython):
    def custom_complete(self, event):
        return [list of completions]

    ipython.set_hook('complete_command', table_complete, re_key = '%%magic')

load_ipython_extension(get_ipython())
```

to show autocomplete for a custom cell magic, but this only works on the same line (e.g. `%%magic word`), but not in the body of the cell...so how do I make that regex multiline to keep completing?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't know. Will read those resources better. Redacted to only one question. Thanks!

Comment: I think the answer to the question you since removed, about the annotation with color guide you see in the autocomplete pop-up listing when you press tab, is that it just comes from evaluating the Python type of the objects. In other words whether it is a function or class or statement is inherent in the code and so it notes that.